# seed that controls the order of a random function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random-seed

I used Matlab kmeans function to do clustering for two datasets: data1 and data2. 
I have three main files, containing the following codes respectively,

```
result1 = kmeans(data1, 4);
result2 = kmeans(data2, 4);

r1 = kmeans(data1,4);

r2 = kmeans(data2,4);
```

I noticed that result1 and r1 are the same, but result2 and r2 are slightly different. I believe that this is caused by the randomness in the kmeans algorithm. In the 1st and 2nd files, data1 is executed first and thus kmeans uses the same "seed". In the 1st and 3rd files, data2 is executed at different stages. The kmeans used for result1 has an effect on the following kmeans.

My question is: can we set up seed in certain way so that r2 and result2 are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control random number generation in MATLAB using the [`rng`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) function. With it, you can capture the state of the random number generator before running your code, then set the random number generator back to that state before you run it again, ensuring you get the same results. For example:

```
rngState1 = rng;  % Capture state before processing data1
result1 = kmeans(data1, 4);
rngState2 = rng;  % Capture state before processing data2
result2 = kmeans(data2, 4);

...

rng(rngState1);  % Restore state previously used for processing data1
r1 = kmeans(data1,4);

...

rng(rngState2);  % Restore state previously used for processing data2
r2 = kmeans(data2,4);
```

Since you're processing data in separate files, this might mean [saving and loading](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/save-load-and-delete-workspace-variables.html) the state variables to and from a MAT-file to do what I've outlined above. Another option is simply to set the seed to a given value before processing each data set:

```
rng(1);  % Set seed to 1 for data1
result1 = kmeans(data1, 4);
rng(2);  % Set seed to 2 for data2
result2 = kmeans(data2, 4);

...

rng(1);
r1 = kmeans(data1,4);

...

rng(2);
r2 = kmeans(data2,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use non-random initialization:

```
start = data1(1:4,:); % This is not necessarily a good initialization!
result1 = kmeans(data1, 4, 'Start',start);
```

Don't copy-paste the code above, it is just for illustrative purposes. But you might have a good strategy to initialize your means non-randomly, it depends on your data how you could do this. For example for 2D data within a rectangular domain you can select the four corners of the domain.